# Parallel Parsing C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, parsing, parallel-processing

I want to do something(strange) in C++ with some major idea as below:

1. Receive a String of commands (SCPI commands) used to control instruments. Could receive in vector or buffer.
2. Parse the string and extract individual commands (if the string contains multiple commands)
3. Parse the individual commands to extract the mnemonics and arguments (elements of a SCPI   command).
4. Match the Mnemonics with an already available Parser Table

The funny thing is I already have a working solution but it's so slow when it comes to batch processing/parsing of commands.

I am looking to do it in a way that the overhead decreases. One idea I have is to move from SERIAL to MULTITHREADED approach (like doing different stuff as mentioned above in different threads and utilizing the CPU cores to a maximum).

I would therefore, need suggestions and tips on how and where to start ?

Comment: Not really knowing SCPI, but are all "commands" you receive of the same length? Are there any relationship between commands, any sequencing? (Meaning some commands must run before other commands.) Start with those questions to see which parts of the code could possibly be split into threads..

Comment: [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) :-)

Comment: What means "slow"?

Comment: @ZDF By "SLOW" I mean when you're testing a device using the instrument and there is a lot of commands going in and out the overall response is not efficient. For a small number of commands that's fine but when you have an automated system of testing it adds up to a lot of overhead.

Comment: @Joachim The commands are actually different; some of them take parameters while others don't. And there is no sequencing of commands. The main task is to parse the commands coming to/from the test instrument and then it does some calculations (which are already implemented using multi-threading)...

Comment: I am not familiar with SCPI. What takes time: the actual parsing, or the processing of commands? The parsing should be fast enough. If the processing is the problem, you could use a classic producer/consumers approach.

Comment: I will try what you have suggested . Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Processing commands in parallel is a matter of separating the logic that resolves a command and running it on it's own thread, piping it commands as they come in from the parser.

Parsing a serial stream in parallel however is another matter. In order to effectively batch command parsing you need to be able to split the commands without knowing their content.

One approach could be to make use of a packet structure to associate command chunks together and make sure that parallel parsers receive all chunks required to construct a command.

```
struct CommandPacket
{
   uint8_t commandID;
   uint8_t dataLength;
   uint8_t data[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];
}
```

You might simply pipe packets to a parser using the modulus of the id to evenly spread the load.

```
int parserIndex = packet.commandID % parserCount;
```